# WebRTC - How to establish a peer connection after offers and answers

Tags: node.js, webrtc

I have a node.js running which the users will connect to. The offer and answer will be generated and sent through node.js.

I'm trying to establish a peer connection and send over a camera stream. I tried my code without using ICE candidates as the computers where in the same subnet. I tried to implement ICE afterwards. I'm not sure if i've done it right though or if it's even needed if the computers are on the same subnet.

```
var localStream;
//Connect to signaling server
var signalingChannel = io.connect('http://85.134.54.193:8001');
console.log("Connect to signaling server");
var servers = null;

var video1;
var video2;
var audio1;
var audio2;

var cfg = {"iceServers":[{"url":"stun:stun.l.google.com:19302"}]};//{ "iceServers": [{ "url": "stun:stun.l.google.com:19302" }] };
var con = { 'optional': [{'DtlsSrtpKeyAgreement': true}, {'RtpDataChannels': true }] };
var peerConnection;

//Runs after the page has been loaded
window.onload=function(){
    //Gets ID for the video element which will display the local stream
    video1 = document.getElementById("audio1");
    //Gets ID for the video element which will display the remote stream
    video2 = document.getElementById("audio2");
    audio1 = document.getElementById("audio1");
    audio2 = document.getElementById("audio2");
    }

//Start button function
function caller(){
    peerConnection = new webkitRTCPeerConnection(cfg);
    navigator.webkitGetUserMedia({'audio':true, video:true}, function (stream) {
        console.log("Got local audio", stream);
        video1.src = window.webkitURL.createObjectURL(stream)
        peerConnection.addStream(stream);
    }, 
    function ( err ) {
        console.log( 'error: ', err );
    });

    console.log("Calling");
    //Create Offer
    peerConnection.createOffer(function (offerDesc) {
        console.log("Created local offer", offerDesc.sdp);
        peerConnection.setLocalDescription(offerDesc);
    }, function () { console.warn("Couldn't create offer"); });

    //ICE Candidates Generator
    peerConnection.onicecandidate = function(evt) {
        //When The Ice Gathering is complete
        if (evt.target.iceGatheringState == "complete") {
            //Create a new offer with ICE candidates
            peerConnection.createOffer(function(offer) {
                console.log("Offer with ICE candidates: " + offer.sdp);
                signalingChannel.emit('offer', JSON.stringify(offer));
                console.log("offer sent");
                signalingChannel.on('answer', function(data){
                    console.log("Receive answer");
                    //The answer is set as the remote description for the offerer
                    peerConnection.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(JSON.parse(data)));
                    console.log("Set remote desc");
                    peerConnection.onaddstream = gotRemoteStream;
                    console.log("Add remote stream to peer connection");
                });
            });
        }
    }

}

function answerer(){
    peerConnection = new webkitRTCPeerConnection(cfg);
    navigator.webkitGetUserMedia({'audio':true, video:true}, function (stream) {
        console.log("Got local audio", stream);
        video1.src = window.webkitURL.createObjectURL(stream)
        peerConnection.addStream(stream);
    }, 
    function ( err ) {
        console.log( 'error: ', err );
    });
    console.log("Answering");
    //Listen for offer
    signalingChannel.on('offer', function(data){
        console.log("Offer Received");
        //Set the remote description from caller's local description
        peerConnection.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(JSON.parse(data)));
        //Generate answer after getting the remote description
        peerConnection.createAnswer(function(sessionDescription) {
                //Set local description
                peerConnection.setLocalDescription(sessionDescription);
                //The local desc will be the answer sent back to offerer
                signalingChannel.emit('answer', JSON.stringify(sessionDescription));
                console.log("Answer sent");
                });
    });

}

function gotRemoteStream(event){
    video2.src = window.webkitURL.createObjectURL(event.stream);
}
```

Comment: Did you ever figure it out?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sequence of events I have working today (Feb 2014) in Chrome.  This is for a simplified case where peer 1 will stream video to peer 2.

1. Set up some way for the peers to exchange messages.  (The variance in how people accomplish this is what makes different WebRTC code samples so incommensurable, sadly.  But mentally, and in your code organization, try to separate this logic out from the rest.)
2. On each side, set up message handlers for the important signalling messages.  You can set them up and leave them up.  There are 3 core messages to handle & send:

   - an ice candidate sent from the other side ==> call `addIceCandidate` with it
   - an offer message ==> `SetRemoteDescription` with it, then make an answer & send it
   - an answer message ===> `SetRemoteDescription` with it
3. On each side, create a new peerconnection object and attach event handlers to it for important events: onicecandidate, onremovestream, onaddstream, etc.

   - ice candidate ===> send it to other side
   - stream added ===> attach it to a video element so you can see it
4. When both peers are present and all the handlers are in place, peer 1 gets a trigger message of some kind to start video capture (using the `getUserMedia` call)
5. Once `getUserMedia` succeeds, we have a stream.  Call `addStream` on the peer 1's peer connection object.
6. Then -- and only then -- peer 1 makes an offer
7. Due to the handlers we set up in step 2, peer 2 gets this and sends an answer
8. Concurrently with this (and somewhat obscurely), the peer connection object starts producing ice candidates.  They get sent back and forth between the two peers and handled (steps 2 & 3 above)
9. Streaming starts by itself, opaquely, as a result of 2 conditions:

   - offer/answer exchange
   - ice candidates received, exchanged, and added

When I want to change the stream, I go back to step 3 and set up a new peer connection object and do the whole offer/answer again.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you wait for ICE to complete before creating an answer? what about doing them simultaneously? That might help, as it is just meant to work simultaneously. If you can post your logs after this when it would still not work we can try debugging it even further. If you want to see an audio-only example of this (it sends both music-audio and microphone-audio) check [here](http://codetank.herokuapp.com/mp.html), and the [github source](http://github.com/marijns95/codetank). Server made with node.js and ws plugin. The audio connection works with webRTC.